# Coefficient of Quasi-Randomized Control Trial with different Treatment Intensity

Tags: experiment-design, causality, propensity-scores

I need some thoughts on the following problem which I have not been able to solve. I have thought of using different methods including OLS, FE, and PSM but I am not sure what to use. Here is the setting:

There was a random lottery played for 3 consecutive years at my company (a large corporation). The lottery played different amounts ranging from $40,000 to $200,000. There were a different number of employees who participated each year. Some employees participated all three years and some even won in consecutive years.

My goal is to estimate the effect of winning the lottery on their discretionary spending (going to restaurants). In essence, this is a quasi-experimental design as the lottery is obviously random and the workers share similar characteristics.

Nonetheless, there is different "treatment intensity." My questions are: 1) would a binary treatment dummy capture the average treatment effect of winning the lottery? 2) how can I account for different treatment intensity? 3) what would be the interpretation of the regression coefficient?